# how to change the pcolor of neighboring patches?

Tags: netlogo

I'm a netlogo beginner and hope to get some help.

I'm trying to create a patch at coordinates 0,0 and then set the color to red, including all 8 surrounding patches.

How can i do so?

I tried something like,

```
ask patch 0 0 [set pcolor red of neighbors]
```

I know it's wrong, 'cos i'm stuck. Hope someone can give me a tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
ask patch 0 0 [
  set pcolor red
  ask neighbors [
    set pcolor red
  ]
]
```